# What (apart from Software Updates) can update system executables?

Tags: updates, checksums

When the Software Updater pops up with some updates to install, I run rkhunter just before applying them, as a check that my installation is clean.  When done, I update rkhunter's file signatures.

Recently I've found rkhunter reports changes to system and important executables between these updates.  Cron and curl, even bash itself, and today before the latest update I find that dpkg has changed.

Is this evidence of some exploit?  Standard malware checks including rkhunter itself never report problems.

I could compare md5 checksums if I knew where to find them for a suspect executable.  I imagine the software update process does some such check.  My /etc/apt/sources.list contains only standard repositories.  Could one of my PPAs be doing this/be suspect in some way?  And could a PPA update these in some way other than via Software Updater?  I don't run Livepatch.

Comment: unattended upgrades? Check the logs at /var/log/apt

Comment: Yes!  I have unattended upgrade switched on for security upgrades!  All these unexpected changes are security upgrades.  I should have worked that out for myself.

Comment: @adrianhb no problem :D

Comment: Glad your system is OK and you worked it out.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this evidence of some exploit? Standard malware checks including rkhunter itself never report problems.

No. This kind of software tends to show false positives.

> Could one of my PPAs be doing this/be suspect in some way? And could a PPA update these in some way other than via Software Updater?

All of our updates come from the repositories and all of the security updates come from the security repository. Ubuntu backports security patches so that software (like apt and cURL) can stay secure without breaking other software by changing the version.

> What (apart from Software Updates) can update system executables?

Any package you install that has apt or curl as a dependency and has a higher version number listed than in the normal repositories for your release is going to error out due to a version mismatch. Lower versions would not trigger an update but if the package has a "at most this version" it would also error out. Mixing releases would trigger to install the highest version; pinned packages fix the version. But those two are unlikely.

Unattended upgrades for security patches is most likely the reason.

One way to go about with this is to check three things:

Check the date:

```
$ ls -ltr /usr/bin/apt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18824 apr  8 12:22 /usr/bin/apt
rinzwind@discworld:~$ ls -ltr /usr/bin/curl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 260328 mei  9 14:34 /usr/bin/curl
```

- Dutch months ;)
- So april 8th for apt
- And may 9th for curl

Check the version/package

```
$ apt list apt
Listing... Done
apt/jammy,now 2.4.5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
apt/jammy 2.4.5 i386
```

and ...

```
$ apt list curl
Listing... Done
curl/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
curl/jammy-updates,jammy-security 7.81.0-1ubuntu1.2 i386
```

Check the changelog for the command ...

- [curl](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy/+source/curl/+changelog) shows ...

> curl (7.81.0-1ubuntu1.2) jammy-security; urgency=medium
>
> - SECURITY UPDATE: percent-encoded path separator in URL host
>
>   - debian/patches/CVE-2022-27780.patch: reject percent-decoding host
>     name into separator bytes in lib/urlapi.c.
>   - CVE-2022-27780
> - SECURITY UPDATE: CERTINFO never-ending busy-loop
>
>   - debian/patches/CVE-2022-27781.patch: return error if seemingly stuck
>     in a cert loop in lib/vtls/nss.c.
>   - CVE-2022-27781
> - SECURITY UPDATE: TLS and SSH connection too eager reuse
>
>   - debian/patches/CVE-2022-27782.patch: check more TLS details for
>     connection reuse in lib/setopt.c, lib/url.c, lib/urldata.h,
>     lib/vtls/gtls.c, lib/vtls/openssl.c, lib/vtls/nss.c, lib/vtls/vtls.c,
>     lib/vssh/ssh.h.
>   - CVE-2022-27782
>
> -- Marc Deslauriers   Mon, 09 May 2022 08:34:24 -0400

- [apt](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy/+source/apt/+changelog) shows ...

> apt (2.4.5) unstable; urgency=medium
>
> - Only protect two kernels, not last installed one (LP: #1968154)
> - Fix segfault in CacheSetHelperAPTGet::tryVirtualPackage()
>
> -- Julian Andres Klode   Fri, 08 Apr 2022 12:22:23 +0200

The changelog date match my executable date so to me an indicator it all checks out. I update every day and I generally only use trusted repositories.

Comment: Thanks for your long reply.  apt list -a shows that all these upgrades are security ones.  I didn't remember that I had switched on unattended upgrades for security patches.

Answer (score 0):

This was a silly question, but other people may have the same one.  I had unattended updates enabled for security updates, shown by

```
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
```

containing the line

```
"${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-security";
```

uncommented (among others).
For all the executables that were unexpectedly updated, e.g. bash,

```
apt list -a bash
```

showed the installed version was from the -security repositories.  Rinzwind's comment shows other ways that you can verify  this.